# How to center view on screen while ViewPager has page bigger than screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, centering

I have a `ViewPager` (standard one) which is put in `ScrollView` (in case the page will be bigger then screen. On each page I have a `Spinner` (progress bar) for show data loading. The `Spinner` is centered on page.

But when the page is bigger then screen the `Spinner` isn't centered on screen because it centered on page and `Spinner` on bottom the screen (or even hidden e.g. below the screen).

So how to set `Spinner` centered on screen (not on page)?

***UPDATE:*** *The Spinner has to be on page in viewpager because each page has to load some data form server and spinner indicate the loading process for each page separately.*

here is placement of pager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is a page layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/my_gird"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_text"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="!!!!!!" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your spinner into your ViewPager activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
         <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        /> 
    </RealativeLayout>
```

Hope this help

Comment: It not solves my problem because I have to access to progress bar form page in view pager.

Comment: @LunaVulpo can't you provide a callback for that?

Comment: @Shark maybe I could but finally I solve my problem by programatically measuring the screen size and set the progressBar in right place.